# Better code indentation

Tags: php, optimization

I'm sure code indentation is a basic requirement for correct development. I have checked out may pages to learn more and results of my coding are below.

I like to share that here to receive opinions and suggestions.

```
<?php
include_once "../../config.php";

// Start
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
$level = 2;

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) OR ($_SESSION['user_levell'] > $req_level)) {
    header("Location: $url/dashboard.php?error=1"); exit;
}

// Load permissions
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT conf
    FROM adm_users
    WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']
);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
    $access = $row['acess'];

if (($_SESSION['user_level'] != "1") && ($access_config != "1")) {
    header("Location: index.php?error=1"); exit;
}
// End

include_once "$url/includes/head.php";
include_once "$url/includes/menu.php";


// Load ser
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT  *
    FROM    adm_ser
    WHERE   ser_id='$ser_id'
");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
    $ser_id = stripslashes($row['ser_id']);
    $ser_cod = stripslashes($row['ser_cod']);       
    $ser_cd = stripslashes($row['ser_cnpj']);
    $ser_name = stripslashes($row['ser_name']);
    $ser_status_id = stripslashes($row['ser_status_id']);

// Dropdown Ser Status
$sql2 = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM adm_ser_status
    WHERE status_id=".$ser_status_id
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    $status_id_dropdown = $row['status_id'];
    $status_de_dropdown = $row['status_desc'];
}  
?>
```

Comment: There is no One True Coding Style. Decide on something and, most importantly, stick to it. (So far, everything look sensible, but I prefer to align the `=` of related assignments)

Comment: I think your coding style is ok, also bearing in mind what Jon said. However, if you are looking to set yourself a style to stick to, I suggest [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), which is adopted by Zend, Symfony, Amazon to name a few

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to indent your `$ser_` value assignments.  Indentation should be left for within a class, method, loop, etc as you do for most of your other code.  I notice that you separate your MySQL statement, which can be done, but on such a simple query, really isn't needed as the only purpose for doing that is to help readability when it is a complicated query. ^^

On a side note, `mysql_` functions are [deprecated now](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and you should switch to [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (or the MySQLi class), or (preferably) [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's highly recommend to use one one off "official" coding standars like

- Zend (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html)
- Pear (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)
- PSR (https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted)

I highly recommend to use PSR-1, PSR-2.

If you want to check what codding style "errors" you have - use php code sniffer:

- http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.php
- http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/11/php-coding-standards/
- You even can integrate in your editor (if you use phpstorm http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/checking-your-code-with-php-code-sniffer-in-phpstorm-4-0/) or example Sublime Text 2(http://www.soulbroken.co.uk/2012/02/php_codesniffer-plugin-for-sublime-text-2/)

Comment: agree. Adoption much better than invention.